# How to find out a type of attribute of DynamoDb table?

Tags: asp.net, .net, amazon-dynamodb

everyone!

I have the following situation: client sends attributes, which he wants to retrieve from table, for example "Id, Name, Price", and I should send them , having been mapped them before. The problem is, how to find out what are the types of given attribute? I want to know where the data of Price attribute is stored: `val["Price"].N` or `val["Price"].S` or somewhere else? Is there any way to find it out?

Thank you for any advice!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the .net SDK specifically, but if you are looking for what data type each attribute is stored in DynamoDB, you could do the calls with the [low level client in the SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelDotNetItemsExample.html), as opposed to the DocumentClient. The low level client returns DynamoDB's native JSON format and will tell for each attribute if it is a string, number, map, etc.